# Extrema of 1st derivative at the point of inflection

Tags: calculus

Let $x_0$ be the point of inflection of a function $f(x)$, then prove that $x_0$ is the point of extremum for $f'(x)$.
$$$$(Point of Inflection Definition : The point where $f"(x)$ is either $0$ or doesn't exist and $f'(x)$ exists and $f"(x)$ changes it's sign while passing through this point)
$$$$Case 1: when $f"(x)=0$, In this case we see that $f'(x)$ satisfies all the conditions of the first derivative test so $f'(x)$ has an extrema at $x=x_0$
$$$$Case 2: In this case if $f'(x)$ is continuous at $x=x_0$ then again it satisfies all the conditions of the 1st derivative test so again $f'(x)$ has an extrema at $x=x_0$
$$$$But I want to know that how to prove this when $f'(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=x_0$

Comment: "Point of Inflection Definition: ... $f'(x)$ exists" - with your definition, doesn't $f'(x)$ have to be continuous at $x=x_0$ (so that $ f'(x_0)$ exists) for a point of inflection?

Comment: But why $f'(x)$ may be discontinuous at $x=x_0$

Comment: Can a function have an extremum at such a point (where it is not continuous)?

Comment: The function may or may not have an extremum at such a point